# How to format number = "$lowprice" to currency

Tags: php, currency

How to format number = "$lowprice" to currency

```
$price_content .= '<span>';
if ($currency_sympol) $price_content .= get_post_meta($id,$wprs_prefix.'lowprice', TRUE);
$price_content .= '<sup>'.$currency_sympol.'</sup>';
$price_content .= '</span>';
```

Comment: Please format code as code and not as normal text.

Answer (score 0):

To format a number as currency use the `money_format()` function. ([Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php))

```
$lowprice = 1234.56;

// Italian national format with 2 decimals
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'it_IT');
echo money_format('%.2n', $lowprice) . "\n";
// Eu 1.234,56
```

Since the currency is derived from the server locale, you might need to change it (see sample).

Comment: If you found that the answer solves your problem, please [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)